# NAS Solution that Does Not Generate Index Directories

Tags: nas

I'm looking for a reasonably cheap network attached storage solution for small business use. I'm not terribly picky about features, but I'd prefer a pre-made option that I don't have to fiddle with excessively. But my biggest requirement is that it must **not** generate hidden index directories throughout its shares.

In my experience, this behavior seems rather common among pre-built NAS boxes; my last two (a WD My Book Live and a Synology Diskstation, respectively) have done it, and it's caused no end of problems. The index directories work their way into all sorts of places they shouldn't be...source folders, version control, builds...you name it.

So my question is, can anyone recommend a model or brand of NAS that is confirmed to not have this terribly annoying behavior?

Comment: Generally you can tell the NAS not to expose these over the network, even if they generate them. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: @JMY1000 They aren't _visible_ over the network, but if you grab an entire directory at once, you're going to get an index directory as a subfolder. That's the whole problem. I'd be very surprised if there was a NAS solution that effectively screened these directories out over all available communication methods.